# Dart Flutter : How to use multiple widget in ternary operator inside a flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna use multiple widget in ternary operator like this.
But it's error.Can I do?

```
Container(
  child: (if value != null)
  ? Widget1(...),Widget2(...)
　　　　: const SizedBox.shrink(),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping each of those Widgets inside a `Column()` (or into an other widget you find appropriate for your app as Row).

```
Container(
  child: value != null
  ? Column(children:
                [Widget1(...),
                 Widget2(...)]
            )
　　　　: const SizedBox.shrink(),
)
```

Comment: `Container` does not have a `children` property.

Comment: My bad, thanks for letting me notice. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you!! I can do what I want

Answer (score 0):

`Container` only support a single child widget, so you cannot use it this way. What you can do is use something like `Column` or `Row`:

```
Container(
  child: value != null
    ? Column(children: [Widget1(...), Widget2(...)])
　  : const SizedBox.shrink(),
)
```